# having the same object as return type and input argument for a method in Java

Tags: java

```
public static void prepareOutput (Output[]  parOutput, Input inputObj) 
{
    int arraySize  = parOutput.length;
    Output[] output = new Output[arraySize];
    for(int i=0; i<arraySize; i++)
    {           
        if(parOutput != null && parOutput[i].getSubscriptionsX7() != null)
        {
            output[i] = new Output();
            output[i] = setLevel1OutputObj(parOutput[i],inputObj, output[i]);
            output[i] = setLevel2OutputObj(parOutput[i],inputObj, output[i]);
            output[i] = setLevel3OutputObj(parOutput[i],inputObj, output[i]);
            output[i] = setLevel4OutputObj(parOutput[i],inputObj, output[i]);
        }   
    }
    inputObj.setSubscriberInfoOutput(output);
}
```

I have main Input `object o1` which consists of `object o2`. 
`Object o2` consists of `object o3`.
`Object o3` consists of `object o4`.

Here I am passing the same output object in the argument and have it as return type as well. Can it be coded better?

Comment: Describe the problem you are attempting to solve.

Comment: I don't understand the question, but I can see `if (parOutput != null)` is in the wrong place.

Comment: Same here.  The way you asked question makes no sense to me.  What are you trying to tell on "object o1 consists of object o2....." ?

Comment: and there is no "return type" for your method.  Its return type is void.  Can you try to ask clearer?

Comment: `setLevelXOutputObj` makes no sense to me too.

Answer (score 0):

Input `inputObj` make it class member, so your method have only `parOutput` as parameter.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "global"

Comment: @AdrianShum global in context of the method, out side of method and also I said class member I think its easily understoo.

Comment: I agree with @AdrianShum.  "Global" and "class member" are not the same thing.  Java doesn't even really have "globals", the closest you can get is `public static` (and hopefully, `final`), which is still different from a class member variable.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to write a utility/helper function, like so:

```
public static Output configuredOutput(Output source, Input input) {
    if (source.getSubscriptionsX7() == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Output result = new Output();
    result = setLevel1OutputObj(source, input, result);
    result = setLevel2OutputObj(source, input, result);
    result = setLevel3OutputObj(source, input, result);
    result = setLevel4OutputObj(source, input, result);

    return result;
}
```

...and then implement your loop-body in the calling code like:

```
if(parOutput != null && parOutput[i].getSubscriptionsX7() != null) {
    output[i] = configuredOutput(parOutput[i],inputObj);
}
```

Another option, and what I *think* you're actually asking about, is to implement [method-chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).  To do that you'd have to refactor your `setLevelXOutputObj` functions to be instance methods on the `Output` class.

If you did so, you'd then be able to rewrite your loop-body with something like:

```
Output source = parOutput[i];
output[i] = new Output().setLevel1OutputObj(source, inputObj)
                        .setLevel2OutputObj(source, inputObj)
                        .setLevel3OutputObj(source, inputObj)
                        .setLevel4OutputObj(source, inputObj);
```

The fact that you're always passing the `Object` that you're working with as the final argument to your static functions is a good indication that your static functions would be more appropriately implemented as instance methods.

Note that as pbabcdefp states, you likely also want to look at your `parOutput != null` check.  You don't really have it in a reasonable place, as your current code will throw a `NullPointerException` if `parOutput` is ever actually `null`.